# Twilio: Test message content without a physical phone

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

Disclaimer: I am completely new to Twilio.

I want to see if the content of the SMS is what I expect it to be, and if it doesn't return any error messages, without actually sending it to my phone.

It just seems very time consuming to send a message to my phone everytime I make a change to the code to check if it still works properly.

Also how can I use the test credentials to not get charged for sending message or receiving an automatic response. (I know it is explained on the Twilio site, but I found it confusing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

My recommendation is that if you want to ensure a message definitely appears as you expect on a phone, then you need to test with a phone.

If you are just testing that the text you are sending as a message is correct then I would stub out the Twilio methods in development to just log the message rather than contact the API.

Test credentials are useful for making sure you are making calls to the API successfully, however they will not send messages. There is no use of test credentials for receiving messages.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thank you! 

Sorry for the dumb question, but: If I'd want to send an SMS using the API and created a `php` file on my server, like in the [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages), how would I call the file? How would I get the code to execute?

Comment: Also, I read the short tutorial in your profile, but I noticed you are using Ruby. Could you argue for a reason not to use PHP, which I am familiar with  and switch to Ruby for Twilio purposes? Or is it entirely a personal preference?

Comment: If you are familiar with PHP then stick with it, there's no need to learn Ruby for Twilio, that's just one of my favourites. On my Mac (and I guess on Linux systems too) I can run PHP files, like the one from the example, by opening a command line and running `php file.php`. I'm not sure about Windows though, if that's what you're using.